# Demultiplex / delegate for GWT event system, using enums

Tags: events, gwt, event-handling

I have an enum, say Fruits { Apple, Banana, Cherry }. I want to write a event subsystem for my application so that I can have the following pattern :

```
class AppleListener implements HasFruitPriceChangeListener<Apple> {
    onFruitPriceChange(int newPrice) { 
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

and a single listener, that can delegate tasks in the following format:

```
class FruitPriceListener {
     public void onPriceChange(EnumMap<Fruits, Integer> pricePoints) {
         // for each fruit, throw the event as
         // FruitPriceChange.fire(Apple, newPrice);
     }
}
```

Is there a way to do it in the above manner ? I would probably like to use ValueChangeEvent, but creating another 1 event and handler is also fine too. What I do not want to do is have event/class definitions for each item, like AppleFruitPriceChangeEvent, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I came up with was:

1. Create the enum, and associate a GwtEvent.Type with them:

   ```
   enum Fruits {
     Apple, Banana, Cherry;

     public GwtEvent.Type getGwtEventType() {
       return new GwtEvent.Type();
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create a new event.

   ```
   class FruitPriceChangeEvent extends GwtEvent<?> {

     private final Fruit fruit;
     FruitPriceChangeEvent(Fruit fruitEnum) {
       this.fruit = fruitEnum;
     }

     @Override
     public GwtEvent.Type<?> getAssociatedType() {
       return fruit.getGwtEventType();
     }

     // ... other stuff...

   }
   ```

And then pass it through the whole event handler loop as @Stefan has mentioned. The beauty/hack of this approach is that the SimpleEventBus maintains a `HashMap<GwtEvent.Type, List<HasHandlers>>` from which to get the events, and everytime you create a new `GwtEvent.Type` it generates a unique hashcode (check the implementation for more details).

References:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.gwt/gwt-servlet/2.1.1-rc1/com/google/gwt/event/shared/GwtEvent.java?av=f

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.gwt/gwt-servlet/2.1.1-rc1/com/google/gwt/event/shared/SimpleEventBus.java?av=f

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EventBus for this things, which google suggested ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDuhR18-EdM ) Here how to use it.

Your globl Eventbus

> public static SimpleEventBus bus = new SimpleEventBus();

Your change event:

```
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent;

import eyeweb.client.gwtMessages.JSPollingEntry;

public class EventModified extends GwtEvent<EventModifiedHandler> {

    public final static Type<EventModifiedHandler> TYPE = new Type<EventModifiedHandler>();

    private final Fruits fruits;
    public final JSPollingEntry getPollingMessage(){
        return fruits;
    }

    public EventModified(Fruits fruits) {
        this.fruits = fruits;
    }

    @Override
    public com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.Type<EventModifiedHandler> getAssociatedType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(EventModifiedHandler handler) {
        handler.onUpdateRecivde(this);
    }
}
```

the handler for the event

```
package eyeweb.client.eventbus;

import com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventHandler;

public interface EventModifiedHandler extends EventHandler {

    public void onUpdateRecivde(EventModified handler);
}
```

The event when something changes

```
EventBus.bus.fireEvent(new EventModified(fruite));
```

and the handler which gets the event

```
EventBus.bus.addHandler(EventModified .TYPE, new EventModifiedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMessageSend(EventSendData e) {
                //... do stuff          }
        });
```

Well that sould be all ;)

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Hi Stefan, I found out the way to do it shortly after, so never got to check the question itself. I'll post my solution shortly.